# Rsync from local folder to NAS and delete contents after

Tags: linux, bash, cron, rsync

I have a set of folders on my local nix box and 3 nfs mounts from my NAS. All my permissions seems set to be able to write to my NAS. I also have a mirror of the folder structure on my NAS.

I want to use rsync as a cronjob so that anything new in a folder or subfolder is synced to my NAS with an 'ignore-existing' flag. After the cronjob has synced I want to clear out the folders that are in my local machine so I just have an empty folder structure. Is it anything more than this?

```
rsync -a -v --ignore-existing --remove-source-files src dst
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

I do pretty much the same from cron via a script used on a few machines which has

```
POSTCMD="cd /var/local/backup/${HOSTNAME} && \
      rsync --password-file /root/.rsyncd.passwd \
            --archive \
            --delete-after . ${NASSERVER}::backup/${HOSTNAME}"
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I am not much good with bash. I have the following in a script:

rsync -a -r --ignore-existing --remove-source-files /media/028465cf-b7d2-4bbe-baca-435a7dae1eb1/complete/TV/ /home/osmc/TV/

and a cronjob to run that 2 times a day.

I didnt know what you had with all the stuff after delete-after

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  If you like the answer, feel free to upvote it (click on upwards-facing triangle) and / or also accept it (click on tickmark only you as person asking the questions see).  Learning bash is like other languages and works incrementally too. I use two variables above, nothing special.

Comment: Network rsync:  `machine::path/to/directory`.  See rsync docs.

Comment: Thanks but I thought having them mounted as NFS shares meant I could just go to the local path on linux - I have hit permsission issues this way.

I have now tried with 'machine' from your example as the IP address but get the error:

    sudo rsync -a -r --ignore-existing --remove-source-files /media/028465cf-b7d2-4bbe-baca-435a7dae1eb1/complete/films/ 192.168.1.18::/nfs/Movies/
ERROR: The remote path must start with a module name not a /

Comment: The error is clear, and you confused a path with a remote module. It's all documented.  And you still haven't upvoted...

Comment: as I dont have 15 posts my upvotes dont count for anything. I learnt that by also learning that this place has upvotes. I was not aware! Thanks for the help so far. I am sure the error is clear to someone who uses linux alot, but I dont know waht a 'module name' is as opposed to a /. The remote path in my case actually starts with an IP address not a /...is it just asking for th e/ to be removed so it should read 192.168.1.18::nfs/Movies/

Comment: If your rsync server defines a modules `nfs` to access, yes. This is marginally more advanced but I found it useful.  Sorry about the voting nag; I had forgotten what you can/cannot do at this stage.  Your reputation will grow as you ask and answer...  And given the time spent, I just upvoted your question.

Comment: I think I missed that out from the start. I dont have anything running at the other end (on the NAS). I thought I could just write to the nfs mapped drive. Do I need to setup rsync on the nas?

osmc@osmc:/home/scripts$ rsync -a -r --ignore-existing --remove-source-files /media/028465cf-b7d2-4bbe-baca-435a7dae1eb1/complete/TV/ 192.168.1.18::nfs/TV/             
rsync: failed to connect to 192.168.1.18 (192.168.1.18): Connection refused (111)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(128) [sender=3.1.1]